# Como usar a função "fread" em c para ler uma string de arquivo txt e armazenar essa string em um vetor?

Tags: c

Olá, estou tentando ler um bloco de bytes de um arquivo .txt que contém uma string por exemplo, eu quero armazenar essa string em um vetor de char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


    char nome_arquivo[25];
    int i, j;
    char vetor[50]; //vetor que receberá a mensagem do arquivo nessa função
    //vetor = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    int tamanhovetor;
    char cpy[2];
    char str[5][9];

    printf("Informe o nome do arquivo que deseja abrir:\n");
    scanf("%s", nome_arquivo);

    arquivo_txt = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");

    if(arquivo_txt == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
        fclose(arquivo_txt);
    }

    fread(vetor, sizeof(char), 5, arquivo_txt);

    tamanhovetor = strlen(vetor);

    printf("%s\n%d", vetor, tamanhovetor);  

    /*
    for(i=0; i<tamanhovetor; i++){
        str[i][0]= '\0';
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            sprintf(cpy,"%d", vetor[i]%2);
            strcat(str[i], cpy);
            vetor[i]/=2;
        }
            printf("%s ", str[i]);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: o que o `printf` mostra? Como `vetor` está sendo declarado? O que está dando de errado? Exemplo do arquivo que quer ler? Forneça mais detalhes, por favor

Comment: o printf é para testar se o vetor está com com o conteúdo armazenado corretamente, o conteúdo do arquivo que está lendo

Comment: O que está dando de errado? Exemplo do arquivo que quer ler?

Comment: Note que você está chamando `fclose(arquivo_txt)` dentro do caso em que o `fopen(arquivo_txt, "r")` falha. Isso vai  te dar um erro. Tente substituir a chamada à `fclose()` por um `return;` para impedir que o programa siga adiante tentando usar a variável nula `arquivo_txt`...

Answer (score 1):

Você está copiando 5 bytes do seu arquivo para um *buffer* (`vetor`) e depois chamando `strlen()` nele, que é uma função que conta em qual posição do vetor que ela recebe está o primeiro byte `'\0'`.

Mas você não pôs um `'\0'` depois do final dos *bytes* que você copiou, e como o `vetor` é uma variável local, ele é alocado na pilha, que não tem os seus valores zerados.

Assim, a não ser que você garanta que um dos 5 (por que 5?) *bytes* lidos é nulo, você está muito provavelmente começando a ler os *bytes* que você carregou e seguindo adiante lendo o lixo no resto da `vetor` e depois seguindo adiante lendo valores aleatórios na pilha, até que chega ao fim da mesma e toma uma violação de acesso...

Portanto, você tem que pôr depois da chamada a `fread()` a seguinte linha:

```
vetor[5] = '\0';
```

Assim a *string* fica delimitada e as funções de manipulação passam a fazer sentido.

Answer (score -1):

este codigo pode ajudar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char c[] = "this is tutorialspoint";
   char buffer[100];

   /* Open file for both reading and writing */
   fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");

   /* Write data to the file */
   fwrite(c, strlen(c) + 1, 1, fp);

   /* Seek to the beginning of the file */
   fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);

   /* Read and display data */
   fread(buffer, strlen(c)+1, 1, fp);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Creio que explicar o como usar e, em seguida, mostrar o exemplo de uso seja mais proveitoso. Também tem o fato de você por o `fseek` na resposta, que tá bem fora de contexto, e o `fwrite`, que poderia ser colocado como um extra na resposta, não no escopo principal. Sem falar que seria uma boa o link do conteúdo original do tutorialspoint

Answer (score -1):

`int c =50;  int t=80;  c+t=h;  printf("%i",h);`

Comment: Adicione uma breve descrição explicando por que a sua resposta resolve o problema.